# AndroidTV cast receiver does't launch

Tags: android, casting, android-tv

I have a problem with launch my Android TV cast receiver. I have  android sender app (i used this documentation https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender) It's working with the default cast receiver. Then i integrated cast receiver in my TV app used this documentation https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_tv_receiver. I added new app in Cast console and added package name my Tv app, but my TV app receiver doesn't launching. Can i launch my Tv app how receiver or i should write Web receiver using this https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver